# Подзапрос возвращает несколько значений

Tags: sql

есть запрос:

```
SELECT [ID носителя] FROM [1_5_Место хранения] WHERE [ID произведения] = (
    SELECT  [ID произведения] FROM [1_5_Произведения] WHERE [Название] = 'Лунная соната'
)
```

Если 'Лунная соната' хранится в нескольких копиях, то нижний запрос вернет несколько значений как их обработать, чтобы вывести несколько ID носителя?

Comment: заменить `=` на `IN`

Comment: Кроме `IN` существуют также `= ANY (...` и `= SOME (...`.

Answer (score 3):

Оператор `=` перед подзапросом подразумевает, что только 1 результат придет, если их несколько может прийти, то нужно использовать `IN`:

```
SELECT [ID носителя] FROM [1_5_Место хранения] WHERE [ID произведения] IN (
    SELECT  [ID произведения] FROM [1_5_Произведения] WHERE [Название] = 'Лунная соната'
)
```