# MySql помогите правильно составить запрос с подзапросом

Tags: mysql, sql

Вот запрос

```
UPDATE `bank` SET `money2`=`money2`+2 WHERE `uid` = ( SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `online` > 0); DESC;
```

в ответе ошибка
#1242 - Подзапрос возвращает более одной записи

Как перестроить запрос чтоб обновляла все вернувшие значения?

Comment: ... `where uid in (...)`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подзапрос возвращает несколько значений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/850094/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Comment: `UPDATE 'bank' SET 'money2'='money2'+2 WHERE 'uid' in ( SELECT 'id' FROM 'users' WHERE 'online' > 0);` Если в запросе = то должно вернуться из подзапроса одно единственное значение

Answer (score 1):

Либо IN с подзапросом, либо джойн. При большом числе записей лучше джойн.

```
UPDATE b
INNER JOIN u ON (
    u.id = b.uid 
    AND u.online > 0
)
SET b.money = b.money + 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE `bank` SET `money2`=`money2` + 2 
where exists (
    select 1 from users where users.id = bank.uid and online
)
;
```